# How to change the direction of window minimization effect in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, window, minimize, effects

Is it possible to change the direction of the minimization effect? So when I click the minimize button on a window or press `Super` + `H`, it ALWAYS minimizes toward the top left corner of the screen, no matter the position of the dock. As I have the dock positioned on the bottom center of the screen, I would like the minimization effect to take place toward the bottom center of the screen.